# How prove $\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}\geq n\cdot\frac{d^{2}}{4}$ for $D=\max{A_iA_j}, d=\min{A_iA_j} (1\leq i<j\leq n)$?

Tags: geometry

Let  be n points $A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n$ on plane $(n\geq 3$). Let $D=\max{A_iA_j}, d=\min{A_iA_j} (1\leq i<j\leq n)$. How prove $\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}\geq n\cdot\frac{d^{2}}{4}$?

Comment: Do you mean D and d are the max and min of the product of $A_i$ and $A_j$: $D=\underset{1\le i<j\le n}{\text{maximum}}(A_i\cdot A_j)$?

Comment: If it can help you I found a way to prove that $$\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}\geq n\cdot\frac{d^{2}}{4}$$

Comment: user121270 show your prove

Comment: kabumm $D=max|A_iA_j|$

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: THIS IS NOT A COMPLETE ANSWER

Let's $\varepsilon \gt 0$ is some small number and 
$$
D=\left(\frac{d-\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}\right)m+\delta;0\le\delta\lt\frac{d-\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}};m\in N.
$$ 
Then we have that $$n\le(m+1)^2$$,
so$$n\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}(D-\delta)}{d-\varepsilon}+1\right)^2\Rightarrow n\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}D}{d-\varepsilon}+1\right)^2.$$
Since the last inequality is true for every small enough $\varepsilon$ we have that $$n\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}D}{d}+1\right)^2.$$
By doing some elementary modifications we have $$
\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}\geq n\cdot\frac{d^{2}}{4}.$$
The basic idea of this proof is that all the points should be in some square with side length equal $D$. Then we divide that square by small squares with diagonal length less than $d$. Then we conclude that every such square cannot contain more than one point $A_i$. I could not improve this approach. Maybe someone can improve it and get the desire bound.